# For which one of two bodies that have different velocities the time passes slower?

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation

We were told that velocities are relative so there is no absolute speed.How in that case explain that one of two moving objects has its time ticking slower?

Comment: Each thinks the *other’s* clock is ticking slowly.

Comment: Why then an unstable particle lasts longer if it moves faster?

Comment: We see it live longer because it is moving relative to us. It doesn’t think it lives longer.

Comment: If two unstable particles have different speeds then from perspectives of two different FoR it would be two different results.The FoR with  the same velocity of the first particle should see the second particle last longer and the FoR with speed equal the speed of the other particle the opposite!

Answer (score 0):

*Both objects' times tick slower from the other object's perspective.* This is a real mind-bender when you first encounter it, but it is actually true and does not lead to any contradictions.

Comment: If there are two unstable particles of different speed is it impossible to tell which one will last longer from the perspective of a third frame of reference?

Comment: No, the time dilation of each one would be calculable.